# how to change settings of kafka engine in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse table that uses a Kafka engine.

However, I want to modify the kafka broker list of the table.

Is this possible? There seems to be no documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by deleting and recreating the table with the Kafka engine. Because the table with such engine does not store, but only receives data, this operation should not negatively affect the operation of the service

Comment: what about the management of consumer offsets? wouldn’t the new table attempt to read data from the very beginning of the topic?

Comment: @pdeva We did not test with the change of the list of brokers. Only change the schema of the table (when it was impossible to do it via ALTER TABLE).

Comment: As long as you use the same group name, consumer offsets will be kept in brokers. However, you have to do the operation before the consumer offsets are removed by inactivity (ATM this is 24 hours but default will be changed to 7 days in newer versions. You can change this setting with `offset.retention.minutes` ).